# Popup opening at bottom of page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a button on my page and when it is clicked it shows a list off errors, if any.

However, if after this button click i want to delete a record on another button click, the button opens a popup at the bottom of the page and it is not showing as normal.

It is supposed to dull the screen and show the popup in the middle of the screen.

Below is the code for the first button and also if needed i will provide the asp.

```
Sub DisplayErrors()
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    If error_array Is Nothing Then
        'Response.Redirect("GlobalDBRoutine.aspx?text=" + QuoteNolbl.Text)
    Else
        'For i = 0 To error_array.Length - 1
        '    Dim Trow As New TableRow
        '    Dim Tcell As New TableCell()
        '    Tcell.Text = error_array(i).ToString
        '    Trow.Cells.Add(Tcell)
        '    Table2.Rows.Add(Trow)
        'Next
        Dim Newerror_array() = error_array.Distinct.ToArray
        For i = 0 To Newerror_array.Length - 1
            Dim Trow As New TableRow
            Dim Tcell As New TableCell()
            Tcell.Text = Newerror_array(i).ToString
            Trow.Cells.Add(Tcell)
            Table2.Rows.Add(Trow)
        Next
        MessageBox.Show(" There is a problem in estimation !!! Have a look at the bottom of the page to see if it says anything if not contact IT.")
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the Delete button along with the modalpopup extender that i am using.

Button :

```
            <asp:Button ID="cmdDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" Width="80px" CssClass="ProdPlusCom"
                OnClientClick="Javascript:ShowPopup('DeletePopup'); " />
            <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="cmdDelete_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" DynamicServicePath=""
                Enabled="True" TargetControlID="cmdDelete" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
                CancelControlID="cmdCancel" PopupControlID="DeletePopup">
            </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Popup :

```
<div id="DeletePopup" class="modalPopup" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt;
    width: 200px; height: auto; visibility: hidden">
    <asp:Label ID="lblWarn" runat="server" Text="Are You sure you want to delete this specification?"></asp:Label><br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="cmdCommit" runat="server" CssClass="ProdPlusCom" Text="Ok" />
    <asp:Button ID="cmdCancel" runat="server" CssClass="ProdPlusCom" Text="Cancel" />
</div>
```

Comment: `MessageBox.Show` in asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

> Might be the error with css. post the css of modalPopup

Assuming you want to confirm the deletion from user. You can use ajax confirm button extender as well. ModalPopup is also right but make sure you are giving the css of ModalPopu[

Comment: The CSS is the same that i have used with all of my other popup extenders. So i know there is not a problem with that ... the only problem i think it could be is that it has made a change and not post back.